# One element, two different fonts & font-size. possible?

Tags: css, fonts, font-size, hebrew

I got a webpage displaying english and hebrew information. The default english font is Verdana, and since Verdana does not support hebrew letters, the next option is Arial. 
The problem is that 14px of english (Verdana) are slightly bigger than 14px of the hebrew (Arial).
How can I declare that I want 14px of Verdana, but 16px of Arial on the same element?

Is there any possible way of doing this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems it can't be done... maybe with JS, but that's not the point.
We had to gave up on Verdana.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you surround either the english or hebrew with something like a `<span>` and then style the inline `<span>` accordingly

Answer (score 0):

By different classes?

```
.english { font: 14px Verdana; }
.hebrew { font: 16px Arial; }
```